# Multiple Gradient for single Textview

Tags: java, android

Refering agradient to textview regard as normal action can be achieved in android ,

as below :

```
 android:background="@drawable/gredient"
```

and gradient XML  will be as below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient android:startColor="#B22222" android:centerColor="#000000"
          android:endColor="#B22222" android:angle="0" /> 
    <corners android:radius="15dp"  /> 
 </shape>
```

**what im asking about** is there is away in android to **apply multiple gradients to single textview** consisting of may paragraphs , so each paragraph will has different gradient .

any advice will be appreciated ,

thanks

Comment: i think you can use layer-list here

Comment: @Akki would you please post example code for that and how i can spacify each paragraph for each gradien thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider using a `WebView` instead of `TextView` (if you need more advanced formatting), but if you want to stick to a TextView, [`LineBackgroundSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/LineBackgroundSpan.html) is your friend :)

Although there might be some better solution (most likely involving a custom [`Layout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html)-derived class), here's some sample code that should do what you want just by implementing a special `LineBackgroundSpan` interface:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private Editable mEditable;

    private class MySpan implements LineBackgroundSpan {
        private final Rect rect = new Rect();
        private final Drawable drawable;
        private int next = 0;

        public MySpan(Drawable drawable) {
            this.drawable = drawable;
        }

        @Override
        public void drawBackground(Canvas c, Paint p, int left, int right, int top, int baseline,
                int bottom, CharSequence text, int start, int end, int lnum) {
            if (start == end) return;
            if (next == 0) {
                next = mEditable.nextSpanTransition(start, Integer.MAX_VALUE, MySpan.class);
                rect.left = left;
                rect.top = top;
            }
            if (next == end) {
                rect.right = right;
                rect.bottom = bottom;
                c.save();
                drawable.setBounds(rect);
                drawable.draw(c);
                c.restore();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final Resources res = getResources();
        final Drawable gd1 = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.gd1);
        final Drawable gd2 = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.gd2);
        final Drawable gd3 = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.gd3);
        final Drawable gd4 = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.gd4);

        final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        setContentView(tv);

        tv.setText("Paragraphs with drawable background:\n", BufferType.EDITABLE);
        mEditable = tv.getEditableText();

        final String text = "paragraph text ";
        appendPara("###\n".replaceAll("#", text), gd1);
        appendPara("##############\n".replaceAll("#", text), gd2);
        appendPara("#######\n".replaceAll("#", text), gd3);
        appendPara("###########\n".replaceAll("#", text), gd4);
    }

    private void appendPara(String string, Drawable gd) {
        final int start = mEditable.length();
        mEditable.append(string);
        final int end = mEditable.length();
        mEditable.setSpan(new MySpan(gd), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible with android's default TextView.

You can create your own view, by extending you class with `View`, and use methods like `Canvas.drawText(...)` and `Canvas.drawBitmap(...)` in the view's `onDraw()` method, to create each paragraph with a different gradient.

This can also help you control line-height and paragraph-spacing.

Answer (score 0):

As, you need multiple gradients for your multiple `Paragraphs` then why not to have one `TextView` per `Paragraph` and setting unique gradient for each `TextView`.

If you donot know how many paragraphs you will have,

You must create a `LinearLayout` whose `height` is `wrap-content` and at run time for every paragraph create a `TextView` with `fill_parent width` and `wrap_context height` and add that `TextView` to your parent (`LinearLayout`) view. and in code set `backgrounds` to your `TextViews`.

Comment: i know i can make  TextView for each Paragraph ,and this will solve it , agree with you but i dont want it that way , my text is so long and each paragraph must have different gradient , so if i have for example 50 paragraph , i must have 50 textview and 50 gradient XML , im looking for better solution , by the way thanks alot .